# Удалить строку из txt файла которая будет выведена и имеет определенный текст в конце строки?

Tags: python

У меня есть много строк в txt файле, мне нужно вывести рандомную строку, но чтобы в конце был определенный текст
пример:
asd79asd98as7dasd89a8sd9 | vip
asdsda7sda8s7d0895gs875a | premium

я пишу заданный аргумент вип или премиум и он ищет в txt файле строчку с определенным аргументом

код который у меня есть на данный момент

```
with open("key.txt", encoding='utf-8') as file:
    lines = file.readlines()

random_line = random.choice(lines).strip()

print(random_line)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот этой строкой вы выбираете случайный элемент из списка всех строк:

```py
random.choice(lines).strip()
```

А нужно выбирать из списка с элементами, удовлетворяющими вашему условию. Так что сначала вынесите все подходящие строки в новый список, а уже потом выбирайте случайный элемент из него:

```py
arg = 'vip'

lines_to_choice = []

for line in lines:
    if arg in line:
        lines_to_choice.append(line)

random_line = random.choice(lines_to_choice).strip()
```

Или проще, через генератор:

```py
random_line = random.choice([line for line in lines if 'vip' in line]).strip()
```